# WordPress Learn Dash - registration code - function.php

Tags: jquery, wordpress, registration, learndash

Apologies ahead of time, jQuery is not my strength.

I am looking to add a simple field to the registration page that requires the user to enter the correct code. If the code does not match it will display an error.

I used the following method to add a checkbox with verification however little stuck on what to change to create a numeric field that can be validated. an example of the verification code would be 1234-4321-3456-1264.

```
add_action('learndash_registration_form', 'dbc_ld_registration_terms_and_conditions_field');
function dbc_ld_registration_terms_and_conditions_field() { 
    $message = 'I have read and agree to the <a href="/terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>';
?>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    $("#learndash_registerform #wp-submit").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#ld_registration_terms_and_conditions").click(function(){   
        $("#learndash_registerform #wp-submit").attr('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
}); 
</script>
<style>
#learndash_registerform #wp-submit:disabled {
    opacity: 0.7; 
    cursor: not-allowed; 
}
</style>
<p class="learndash-registration-field learndash-registration-field-terms_and_conditions"><input type="checkbox" id="ld_registration_terms_and_conditions" style="width:auto;margin-right: 14px;"><label for="ld_registration_terms_and_conditions"><?php echo $message; ?></label> <span class="learndash-required-field">*</span></p>
<?php
}
```

Appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: Hi. Are you familiar with HTML5?

Comment: I am, why do you ask?

Comment: HTML5's [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute for validation of input fields might help you. Your code sample shows a non-conventional way of sending JavaScript and CSS to the browser from a WordPress plugin. Since you're using a third-party plugin (that I'm not familiar with), I can't tell if this is correct or not. Please note that customer support questions for third-party services are [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).